# Ember.js: accessing computed alias from component's javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components

I currently have a model that contains a computed alias, as follows:

```
model: DS.belongsTo('device-model'),
manufacturerName: Ember.computed.alias('model.manufacturer.name')
```

I then have a component that is invoked as follows:

```
{{my-component model=model}}
```

Now, in the component's Handlebars template, I can easily access the computed property with `{{model.manufacturerName}}`, however in `my-component.js` I am having trouble getting it to work. I have tried with:

```
console.log(this.get('model').get('manufacturerName'))
```

However, the output is `undefined`. So far, the only way I can get the manufacturer name from my-component.js is:

```
this.get('model').get('model')
.then((model) =>{
  return model.get('manufacturer')
})
.then((manufacturer) => {
  console.log(manufacturer.get('name'))
})
```

So, I'm wondering what is the Handlebars template doing that I can't do in its javascript counterpart? It seems like the Handlebars template is following through the promise, whereas I have to do it manually when it comes to the component's javascript.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is because of your belongsTo relationship. since { async: true} is the default value for relationships in Ember. so it only fetch the related entities when you actually request them. which means your model is not loaded which means your manufacturerName is not loaded since it is an alias of model.manufacturerName.name.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I understand what you mean, but the question is, why can the Handlebars template access that property but its javascript counterpart cannot? What extra step do I have to do in the component's javascript?

Comment: that is strange, I have never encounter this before. either they all work or none of them work. I suspect your console log happen before something loads model 'device-model'. and your {{model.manufacturerName}} in hbs is refreshed or loads after it.  i would try to just load 'device-model'  in your view's route before you call the component like    this.store.findAll('device-model'),

Comment: I am already doing that, in my view's route I'm doing exactly that.